# How to troubleshoot Linksys E4200 Remote Management

Tags: wireless-router, remote-access

My Linksys E4200 is configured for Remote Management, but the router is not accepting the connections. Here's the configuration under **Administration > Management > Remote Management Access**:

> Remote Management: **Enabled**
>   Access via: **HTTP**
>   Remote Upgrade: **Disabled**
>   Allowed Remote IP Address: **Any IP Address**
>   Remote Management Port: **8080**

The router is setup to use **192.168.10.41** as its static Internet IP address, and **192.168.35.1** as its LAN IP address.

I can access the router just fine via its LAN IP address, but I can't make a connection using http://192.168.10.41:8080.

I've tried variations of the settings above (enabled HTTPS, enabled Remote Upgrade, set an IP range of 192.168.10.1-254) but nothing has worked yet. Hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction. Thanks.

**Update:**
To clarify, I have a wired router that connects straight to the T1 modem. It's configured to use 192.168.10.1-254 as its internal LAN range. The E4200 wireless router in question is on that LAN using 192.168.10.41 as its WAN IP address. The E4200's internal LAN range is 192.168.35.1-254. I'm not trying to access the E4200 from the Internet, I'm just trying to access it from its WAN IP address. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work by changing the port number to something other than 8080.

In my case I changed the default port number 8080 to 8800, and then I could access my router from anywhere in the internet. Works with both HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.10.41 is not a public address.  You must ask your ISP for a static public address that is accessible from other location on the net.

Comment: I understand that the router's WAN IP is not public, but I'm not trying to access it from the Internet. I'm trying to access it from its WAN, 192.168.10.0/24. Are you saying that I can only use Remote Management if I set a *public* WAN IP?